# Webpack: How to load raw node `.node` files

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

I am using webpack for the first time.

What loader can I use to load a `.node` file? I am building for node using `target:node` in `webpack.config.js`

I get am error ... Line 1: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by IngwiePhoenix in https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1560,
there is a node-loader for webpack which can be found here:
https://github.com/webpack/node-loader